# Sorting a list of items by alphabetical order when the language has no function to do so?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, sorting, programming-languages

If you would need to sort a list of items, but the programming language does not faciliate this scenario, what would be a good technique to do this? This is hypothetical but worthwhile asking.

Thanks

Comment: This is not a hypothetical question: there are languages with no built-in ability to sort a list of items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two parts to the question:

- how to sort
- how to apply this to alphabetical sorting in general (aka lexicographical sorting).

The two general types of sorting which are most appropriate for alphabetical sorting are:

- a [comparison sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort), where the comparison compares lexicographically
- an MSD [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).

Comparison sorts are more common (partly because they're more general in what they can sort, partly because applying a radix sort to variable-length strings is slightly fiddly compared with a fixed-width radix sort). There are many to choose from with different trade-offs, but all treat the actual comparison of two items as a "black box" separate from the sort algorithm proper.

So the remaining functionality needed is a lexicographic comparison. The way to compare two strings is to look at each character in turn until you find the first pair where they differ, and the left-hand string is "less" if this character is "less". If you don't find a difference then either the strings are the same length (in which case they're equal), or they aren't (in which case the shorter one is "less").

If your character set is ASCII, then it's quite easy to compare characters in alphabetical order (either case-sensitive or case-insensitive). If your character set is full unicode, then you may need either language support, or a third-party library, or a very large table of character properties to get the exact alphabetical order you want.

Answer (score 4):

There's very thorough coverage of this on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

It has a long list of common algorithms, and information about their advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#Sorting) =)

Comment: I didn't downvoted you, but Trie is useful in large data, for minimizing data size, in finding some string is better to sort them, i.e you have a list of 1000 item, each string length is 10 at least, your Trie have depth of `10` and each node in median have a `10` subnode, then for searching a string you should do around `100` check, but if you sort it by a way like QS, you can search it with `10` check, and the complexity of search is not hard as Trie.

Answer (score 0):

The steps are the same as writing any sorting algorithm.  Create a comparison function.  Then using what ever sorting algorithm is appropriate which in most cases is quicksort.  For the comparison function you will have to assign a numeric value to each letter and then compare the letters by rank.  This will give you a lexigraphic sort but thats what I assume you meant any way.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the answer to your question is to understand how Sorting works. A good reference would be Jonathan Shewchuk's [video lectures](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiUvYS2DT6I) on the same.

Give three hours and you are on track with the fundamentals. :)

Answer (score -2):

There's a [really good tool](http://www.google.com) on the internet for this kind of question

As you haven't found it, here's a good starting point: [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)